# Current TabStrip cannot be refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I have problem with Kendo TabStrip. Current TabStrip cannot be refreshed.
For example I have two tabs Teams and Players. I am on Players tab.
When I edit form and click save I want to reload current Players tab with latest changes.
I use this code

```
var tabStrip = $("#myTab").data("kendoTabStrip");
var item = tabStrip.items()[1];
tabStrip.reload(item);
```

but Players tab is not refreshed with latest changes.
If I want Players tab with latest changes. I need to go to Teams tab

```
var tabStrip = $("#myTab").data("kendoTabStrip");
var itemTeams = tabStrip.items()[0];
tabStrip.reload(itemTeams);
```

wait 2 seconds and go to Players tab

```
setTimeout(function(){
var itemPlayers = tabStrip.items()[1];
tabStrip.reload(itemPlayers);
}, 2000);
```

How can I refresh current Players tab without going to Teams tab 
wait 2 seconds and go to Players tab ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get the tabstrip with .getKendoTabStrip() ?

```
var tabStrip = $("#myTab").getKendoTabStrip();
var elementToRefresh = tabStrip.items()[1];
tabStrip.reload(elementToRefresh);
```

Tested from within a tabstrip to relode the same tab after Ajax.BeginForm - OnComplete with desired result!